# jQuery TWBS Pagination implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pagination

I'm new to the pagination plugins and now I decided to work with jQuery TWBS Pagination Plugin.

I saw different tutorials but actually I can't found out how to fetch data to this plugin and set the appropriate numbers of divs that I want to display per page.
My html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content" class="page-content">
         <div class="content">Some text</div>
         <div class="content">Some text</div>
         <div class="content">Some text</div>
         <div class="content">Some text</div>
         <div class="content">Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And JS should be something like this:

```
$('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 2,
        next: 'Next',
        prev: 'Prev',
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            //fetch content and render here
            $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page) + ' content here';
        }
    });
```

I can't understand how can I fetch my divs with "content" class name to this onPageClick function and show only 4 divs per each page.

I know that it is something very easy but I can't make it by myself. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [**Docs**](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#examples),

`twbsPagination` plugin does not support `itemOnPage`

For alternate pagination methods, they are suggesting to use [**flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js**](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Singh Chouhan. Thank you for your fast feedback.
Actually, I finally stoped wasting my time:)
I checked your advice flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js and there is the same issue with a low documentation.
But after some search I found this perfect article, in which developer explains how to use this simplePagination Plugin on example.
Maybe it would be helpful for someone in the future. http://www.bilalakil.me/simplepagination/
You can use this guide for pagination and items per page option.

Answer (score 2):

```
In my case the code below worked, no problems

var $pagination = $('#pagination'),
totalRecords = 0,
records = [],
displayRecords = [],
recPerPage = 10,
page = 1,
totalPages = 0;
$.ajax({
url: "api/Estoque/Gets",
async: true,
dataType: 'json',
data: { startRec:0, search:'', pageSize:0},
success: function (data) {
records = data;
console.log(records);
totalRecords = 10
totalPages = 10
apply_pagination();
}
});
function apply_pagination() {
$pagination.twbsPagination({
totalPages: totalPages,
visiblePages: 6,
first: 'Pimeiro',
prev: 'Anterior',
next: 'Próximo',
last: 'Último',
loop: false,
onPageClick: null,
onPageClick: function (event, page) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "api/Estoque/Gets",
                            async: true,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: { startRec: page, search: '', pageSize: 10 },
                            success: function (data) {
                                records = data;
                                console.log(records);
                                totalRecords = data[0].totalRegistros;
                                totalPages = totalRecords;
                                apply_pagination();
                                gernerateCards();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            gernerateCards = function () {
                let builder = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    builder.push('<div class="col-sm-6">');
                    builder.push('<div class="row">');
                    builder.push('<div class="col-sm-12">');
                    builder.push('<div class="card">');
                    builder.push('<div class="row">');
                    builder.push('<div class="col-sm-6">');
                    builder.push('<div class="card-body text-center">');
                    builder.push('<h5 class="card-title">Champoo</h5>');
                    builder.push('<p class="card-text">Resumo, prestar bem atenção nos dados, para maiores informações clique no botão <span class="text-info font-weight-bold"> detalhes</span> </p>');
                    builder.push('<span>');
                    builder.push('<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info">Detalhes</a>');
                    builder.push('</span>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('<div class="col-sm-6">');
                    builder.push('<div class="card-header card-header-info">');
                    builder.push('<div class="ct-chart chart-item-material"><span class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i> 55% </span> diferença do mês anterior.</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('<br />');
                    builder.push('<p class="card-text">Quantidade  estoque: <span class="text-info font-weight-bold">1589</span></p>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                    builder.push('</div>');
                }

                $('.card-estoque').empty();
                $('.card-estoque').append(builder.join(""));
                builder = [];
            }
```